# How to configure a Minimal Ubuntu installation?

Tags: ubuntu-minimal

I recently re installed Ubuntu using the **mini.iso**, but much to my dismay the **mini.iso** *is not* configured the same way as the Ubuntu desktop ISO some "problems" I'm facing such as:

- An Installation using the regular Ubuntu CD recognizes my active
  network connections in Network Manager, Installing with the
  **mini.iso** gives me a working connection *however* no connections are "active" in Network Manager displaying the message "The system
  network services are not compatible with this version."
- In a regular Ubuntu install connecting an Android phone to the PC
  mounts the phone's internal memory and sd card if present, Using the
  **mini.iso** the phone is detected as it appears with the command `lsusb` but it's not mounted and can't be mounted.
- In the same regards using the phone to tether it's connection to the
  PC via USB, the phone is connected to my (WiFi). In the regular Ubuntu
  install the phone is recognized as a networking device and is used as
  connection `usb0`, while in the  **mini.iso** nothing happens, and
  trying to add the connection to `/etc/network/interfaces` results in
  the OS crashing.

Just to make sure It wasn't a matter of my user not having the correct permissions or a lack of "groups", I've checked with an Ubuntu VM and the groups are the same, the networking files are the same, and the packages (except those of `ubuntu-desktop` such as Unity, Firefox, LibreOffice, and other non-essential software) are Installed in my PC, so what else is there to look for?.

I'm sure I'm missing something, and I'd prefer not to *install Ubuntu again, using the regular cd*.

How can I manage to get the same behaviour/configuration without reinstalling ?

Contents of:

[/var/lib/dpkg/status](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/1195980/)

[dpkg --list](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/1195998/)

[ps aux](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/1196078/)

Comment: Just to confirm, by `mini.iso` you mean the minimal netinstall CD? Or some Ubuntu Remix, etc? What desktop environment are you using now? Also please pastebin the file `/var/lib/dpkg/status` and pastebinit the output of this command: `ls -lct /var/lib/dpkg/info  | grep -P -o "[A-Z][a-z][a-z]\s+\d+.*(?=\.)" | sort | uniq`

Comment: I believe so, it's this one [Minimal CD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD)

Comment: What desktop env/tasksel/additional packages did you install on top of it?

Comment: I get no output from the command you gave me, I installed XFCE (not xubuntu-desktop) ,Chrome, Nautilus, Gnome Tweak Tool, Evince, Inkscape, Gimp, LibreOffice writer, and some others media players and converters all of them appending `--no-install-recommend`.

Comment: Please post output of `dpkg --list`

Comment: Is this 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: It is a 64 bit install.

Comment: output of `ps aux` please.

Comment: This is definitely a consolekit/policykit issue. Which display manager are you using?

Comment: See edit - you need a new version of SLiM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the display manager you are using -- *SLiM 1.3.2* -- DOES NOT integrate with the ConsoleKit/PolicyKit authentication framework used by Ubuntu.

You need to use a display manager which does support CK/PK (e.g. GDM, KDM, LightDM, XDM...), or install the newest SLiM 1.3.4 (from Quantal) which DOES support CK/PK:

- Download and install the following debs:

  1. http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/fontconfig-config
  2. http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/libfontconfig1
  3. http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/slim
- Answer "Yes" to replacing any configuration files with the default versions. Then reboot.

Comment: Do I need to Install fontconfig too?, SLiM installed no problem but fontconfig complains about dependencies.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. If it works, no need to install the new fontconfing. If it doesn't, then you do. Please update me.