# Policykit - E17 without LightDm: Problems with Webcam and Connection manager

Tags: webcam, desktop-environments, policykit, enlightenment, console-kit

I'm using E17 without LightDm ( it saves about 200 mb ram ).

I manage to do that easily and now I'm starting E17 with the old nice `startx` and a `.xinit` file in my home root.

my `.xinit` :
`exec dbus-launch enlightenment_start`

**the issue:**
when I try to change wifi connection (nm-applet) I got a message ' **(32) not authorized to control networking**' and my cam too is not working ( obviously everything is working ok if I pass through `lightdm` \ Unity )

---

**Update 2:**

Because some **alien intelligence** close this question ( sorry but this is not the first time it happens to me ) without any good reason I only can add info here.

- This problem is related to `Console kit`

**Solution**

- I have changed my .xinit :
  `exec ck-launch-session enlightenment_start`

**Extra Steps:**
 - I have also set autologin in the console editing `/etc/init/tty1.conf` :
change last line with this one ( and set your USERNAME )
`exec /sbin/getty -a USERNAME -8 -s 38400 tty1 linux`

- I have add this line to `~/.profile`:
  `[[ $(fgconsole) = 1 ]] && startx -- vt1`
  so startx start automatically at the boot

**Update 3:**
Above solution fix problem with webcam but not for network-managager

**Update 4:**
Here the final 'fix' for webcam and Network manager:

- I have changed my .xinit boot line with that:
  `exec dbus-launch enlightenment_start`

apparently this is the starting point but know everything is working fine don't ask me why :)

Comment: It is not the same question, but the answer is related to what you're experiencing even though you don't use slim (I couldn't mount my phone because i wasn't "authorized" to do so, you can't use your camera because you don't have "permissions"). http://askubuntu.com/questions/185293/how-to-configure-a-minimal-ubuntu-installation

Comment: ConsoleKit and PolicyKit are Security frameworks. (Synaptic is executed with policykit rather than gksu). There must be a way around it, but good luck finding one.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no idea how LightDM or GDM or KDM invoke those, we'll have to wait for someone with more experience.

Comment: hey guys this not a problem related to ubuntu alpha... it is a general problem why here on ask ubuntu people close question without any criteria ?